# Hi, I am stuck in one addError method

Tags: apex, trigger

If any opportunity does not have OpportunityContactRoles with role as "Primary Contact" at the time of making opportunity stage as closed should give error message.

```
public static void primaryDriveContactRequired(List<Opportunity> OppIdList){
   
    List<Opportunity> oppLists=[select id,name,StageName from Opportunity where id in:OppIdList];
    list<Id> oppId=new List<Id>(); 
    for(Opportunity opp:oppLists){
           oppId.add(opp.Id); 
        
    }
    List<Opportunity>  oppList=[SELECT Id, Name,StageName,(SELECT Contact.Name,Contact.Email,Role,Contact.Id,ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRoles) FROM Opportunity where Id In:oppId];
    List<Opportunity> finalList=new list<Opportunity>();
    for(opportunity opp:oppList){
       if(opp.StageName=='Closed'){
           for(OpportunityContactRole ocr:opp.OpportunityContactRoles){
               if( ocr.Role!='Primary Contact'){
                  finalList.add(opp);
               }
           }
        } 
        
    }
    for(Opportunity op:finalList){
        op.addError('Primary Drive Contact required');
    }
    
}
```

Its saying "System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors"
please help.

Comment: Hi. The `addError` method on `SObject` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError)) is only for use in triggers (or code called from a trigger) on records against which the trigger was called. In this case your code seems to be called from the Opportunity trigger, so you can only add errors on the opportunity, not the opportunity contact roles...

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to better explain how your code isn't working as you think it should. If you're getting any error messages, you should include those _verbatim_ (don't paraphrase, you'll leave out important information).

Comment: Adjusting your query to only return Opportunities moving to Closed that do have an OCR role of "Primary Contact" would allow you to then identify the subset of incoming opps that do NOT have such a related OCR role... NB: you also seem to unnecessarily generate the "oppId" list since you can just use "OppIdList" in its place.